# p7zip cannot be executed

Tags: encryption

The icon of **p7zip** does not appear in the applications,
but if I type p7 in the search window,
it says : execute "**p7zip**".
I press it, and nothing happens.

I had installed it with
**sudo apt install p7zip-full p7zip-rar**

and
p7zip                                         16.02+dfsg-7build1
p7zip-full                                    16.02+dfsg-7build1
p7zip-rar                                     16.02-3build1
are included in the list of the system's software packages